# How to resolve Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState stateless component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Hi im trying to set the filter value in function level state im getting the below error.

```
Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
```

also attaching the js image

[image]

I'm using AutoComple in MUI where I'm using inbuild filter method. I want to get the filtered array out of AutoComplete so I used state to set the value. but I'm getting maximum update depth exceeded. Please any one help me on this I'm new to React.